# Aquamacs with AUCTeX, Flyspell and completion

Tags: emacs, aquamacs, auctex

When I'm editing a file in `LaTeX-mode` (I guess it means AUCTeX), and the `flyspell` is enabled, then `M-TAB` is not responding. I cannot get completion of standard LaTeX commands - for example it won't complete `\newc` to `\newcommand`.

I couldn't find information about this around... I'm using Aquamacs with 23.3.1 Emacs on Mac OS X.

Comment: I'm not sure this should have been migrated: It's more in SU's area of competence that it is ours...

Comment: I posted it there in the first place, about 3 months ago, after someone here suggested that this kind of question should be posted there. It wasn't helpful. I think this is an on-topic question, and that the chances it will be answered here are higher.

Comment: From my experience of emacs questions, they don't get answered much. [There are only a dozen or so emacs users on here regularly](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/tex-community-polls/1567#1567) and none of us is that experienced. Whether or not it is on topic is immaterial really: there are more people who know more about emacs on SU than there are here.

Comment: As this question was there (i.e. on SU) for 
quite a while, I asked to try and migrate it here. In any case, if there will be enough people voting to return it to SU - it will happen :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does M-TAB do - anything? Is there a key combination mentioned in your LaTeX menu after "Complete Macro"? The lisp function which should be called is "TeX-complete-macro". Try running it manually by typing

```
\newc
```

and leave the cursor after this and do

```
M-x TeX-complete-macro
```

If this works, then you can probably just rebind the key in your .emacs with

```lisp
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook (lambda () (define-key TeX-mode-map "<M-tab>" 'TeX-complete-macro)))
```

Update: It seems there is a flyspell variable which controls this: `flyspell-use-meta-tab`.
You can probably set this to nil and it will then work.

Comment: For some reason I don't have `M-x TeX-complete-macro`. However, when typing `\newc M-TAB`, if `flyspell-mode` is disabled, then it auto completes to `\newcommand`. If `flyspell` is enabled this doesn't work, and it tries to correct the spelling. I guess there's a conflict between the key bindings which I don't know how to solve. Thanks in advance and for the answer.

Comment: This sounds to me like you dont' have AUCTeX but only some basic LaTeX mode? What happend if you do:

    M-x find-library

and then look for auctex.el?

Comment: It seems like it opens the file `auctex.el`. I do think that `auctex` is installed as I can use features like `C-C C-e` to generate environment or `C-c C-s` to generate sectioning level.

Comment: Hmm this is sounding like you might have an old version of AUCTeX. If you do M-h v (describe variable) and then type "AUCTeX-version", what version do you see?

Comment: I have version 11.86. And I also have another insight - I am using Aquamacs, as I mentioned, and `M-h v` didn't work for me. I had to do instead `M-x describe-variable AUCTeX-version`. Is it relevant?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not using Aquamacs because it changes too many standard Emacs things for my liking but did you try the (add-hook) thing above? Try adding that to your .emacs and restarting emacs

Comment: I tried to add this hook, but still the way `M-TAB` behaves changes depending on whether `flyspell` is enabled or disabled. Odd...

Comment: I just noticed that there is a variable for this in flyspell. Try to change "flyspell-use-meta-tab" to nil. C-h v flyspell-use-meta-tab will give you a link to customise this.

Comment: This seems to be the one thing I missed! Thanks. I hope I won't find other issues which will pop-up as follow ups :) Thanks! Maybe you'd better add it to the answer itself so it will be complete.

Answer (score 4):

FlySpell has a variable that controls that behaviour: `flyspell-use-meta-tab`. The documentation says: Non-nil means that FlySpell uses `M-TAB` to correct word.
So just put this on your `.emacs` file:

```lisp
(setq flyspell-use-meta-tab nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

The folks on the AUCTeX-Mailinglist ( http://www.mail-archive.com/auctex@gnu.org/info.html ) answer questions like this, usually.